# Recover files deleted by dd?

Tags: data-recovery

Imagewriter is a tool like dd with graphic interface and is used to burn the Live CD image into USB drive, I used it to burn Ubuntu image, then later I created LUKS partition in the free space behind the Ubuntu, and then the Ubuntu could not boot. So I redid the same but this time the LUKS partition disapeared, what I think is that the LUKS partition and it's data is still in the free space, can I recover?

Comment: If you only overwrote the partition table and therefore the system simply doesn't know any more that there is a  LUKS volume nd where it would start, you can probably recover that (don't ask me how, though). However, if your second overwriting erased the first 2 MB of the LUKS volume (where the header with the key slots is located), the whole encrypted data is gone forever.

Comment: DD needs 2 MB more space?

Comment: I did not say anything like that. I just said that **if** the first 2 MB of the LUKS partition were overwritten, none of the encrypted data inside it is recoverable. I have no idea what exactly you overwrote.

Comment: That is what I guess, what I don't know is whether the dd writes extra data to other partition, or need more space than the infile.iso to work properly, that would ovverwritten the header where the key slots locates.

Comment: How to position which sector the original encrypted partition starts at?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.